# Can "too" be in the middle of the sentence?

Tags: syntax

I was told in the past, that "**too**" (=also) unlike "**also**", should be in the end of the sentence only ("I want **too** to go there." or "I **too** went there"). Today I read an article in which they put "too" in the middle of the sentence. So it means that one of us (what I was told, or what's in the article) is wrong. What's correct?

> But the student from Aberdeen completely understood how the woman next
>   to her in the store was feeling because she **too** is going through the
>   menopause. ([BBC](https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-scotland-44467555))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although 'too' is very often or mostly found at the end of a sentence, that is not the only place where it may be used: I too like bananas; she too was going through the menopause.

> We usually put too in end position:
>
> Gill’s having chicken. I’ll probably have chicken too.
>
> She looks really tired and she must be really hungry too.
>
> Too can occur immediately after the subject, if it refers directly to
>   the subject. It does not normally occur after a modal or auxiliary
>   verb. We sometimes write commas before and after too:
>
> I too thought she looked unwell.
>
> We, too, have been very pleased to receive the prize on her behalf.

[Also, as well or too? (Cambridge)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/also-as-well-or-too)

Some sources advise a comma before and after a mid-sentence 'too', and before one at the end of a sentence, and others say that commas only be used in these situations:

- When starting a sentence with 'too', in the sense of 'also', a construction many writers avoid.
- To emphasize an abrupt change of thought: He didn’t know at first what hit him, but then, too, he hadn’t ever walked in a field strewn with garden rakes.

[Commas with 'too'](http://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/qanda/data/faq/topics/Commas/faq0004.html)